# how to remove composite key value from primary key in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have table emp in mysql.i add primary key using **constraint pk_id**.i create table like
this.

```
`mysql> create table emp (p_id int(10) not null,name varchar(10),city varchar(10),constraint pk_id primary key(p_id,name));
```

now i want to remove **name**.i tried with following query

```
mysql> alter table emp drop primary key(name);
```

but it is not working.should it possible to remove single value from primary key

Comment: No. Just drop the key and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

You should dropy primary key and recreate

```
ALTER TABLE emp DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE emp ADD PRIMARY KEY ((p_id);
```

And if you need the id auto_incement

```
ALTER TABLE emp MODIFY COLUMN p_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```